# Import local ontology to mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, sparql, ontology, semantic-mediawiki

I just set up a mediawiki project and I have an ontology.owl file i want to upload to the wiki. As per my understanding, I am guessing the classes in my ontology and sub-classes will map on to categories and sub categories respectively in my wiki. I also get that individuals will also be pages. However the whole concept is still a bit confusing. Can anyone give me clear insight as to what I am doing if I am making sense. I actually added semantic mediawiki extension and RDFIO extension and so I now have a sparql endpoint(not sure what exactly this means though) so I should be able to load my rdf code I think. But how do i do this is my question since i have the ontology locally on my computer. I developed it with protege software. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So you're looking for a tool that imports RDF data for you? It's not obvious that such a thing exists.

Comment: Conversion of OWL to RDF might be a start. So https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/ might be of help. SMW per se does not support full ontologies. At SMWCon 2015 Barcelon I'll show the second phase of smartMediaWiki which might be helpful.